# Raspberry Pi Multi-node PC?

Tags: hardware

I have an idea to build a multi-node Raspberry Pi PC running some distro (not Raspbian). But, the problem, **I need to know how to hook up the Raspberry Pi's to work as one** and **it'd be nice to hook it up to some central hard drive,** (if possible). And, is there a way I could do all of this *manually*?

Comment: `is there a way I could do all of this manually` - as opposed to what? having it done automatically when skynet becomes self aware?

Comment: When I mean manually, I mean not to have some program do it for me. And if skynet becomes aware, all my problems would be solved.

Comment: Probably not... how many Raspberry Pi's who you want connected to the setup, and for what purpose?

Comment: For desktop, purpose being: Why not?

Comment: When you say "hook up" are you talking about cabling? For a start just use TCP/IP ethernet or wifi

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the type of work you're wanting to do. Can you be more specific?

You could create a cluster, with a master distributing jobs to the slave nodes -- docker swarm is a possibility. I'd suggest Hypriot for your distro in this case.

Another option would be to have a load balancer, such as haproxy, listening for requests which would then be distributed out among the slaves.

In terms of sharing a drive, you can't do that, but you can have a shared drive via either NFS or weedfs would be good choices.

Comment: I'm trying to have a "PI-PC" to run like a desktop PC, but with multinodes. Nothing too crazy. And wouldn't it be a fire hazard to keep those running. And if it is (which it probably is), what would you recommend for cooling?

Comment: It's *possible* -- you could have an X windows session running on the one plugged into a monitor and then have applications running on the others sending the X session data to the one plugged into the monitor.  I don't know that it'd be a fire hazard -- I've got racks of pi's running without cooling -- though if you're concerned, you could put a fan on them.